# Command for opening PCManFM from the terminal with sudo permission

Tags: command-line, pcmanfm

I am using PCManFM 1.2.5 in Lubuntu but I can't find the command to open it from the terminal with sudo permission for deleting some files. Is there any?

Comment: `sudo pcmanfm`  but be careful; any changes made to settings etc there can cause problems when you exit and use it normally. The program was not intended to be used with elevated (`sudo`) permissions so it has no protections for mistakes.

Comment: `lxsudo pcmanfm-qt`  Maybe you have to install it before. `sudo apt install lxqt-sudo`

Comment: @nobody from the version mentioned I'd guess 18.04, but it's better if we're told @G M.  (`1.2.5-3ubuntu1` is the version of `pcmanfm` found in bionic)

Comment: `lxqt-sudo`  is available in xenial, bionic and newer releases. according to online package search.

Comment: Yeah it is, however for bionic it was supported only 9 months (the last unofficial *Lubuntu Next*) so I'd avoid suggesting it personally; it wasn't part of any LTS release (like Ubuntu Studio in 18.04 though Ubuntu Studio has extended support via PPAs, *Lubuntu Next* never did).  But you're correct.